# How to get data from scriptable object on collision in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a scriptable object that only contains a float variable and I have assigned it to an object, let's call this object A.

I have another object we will call object B, and I want to make it so that when object B collides with object A it gets the data from the scriptable object in object A. I have set up the collision code and all I need to do now is make it so that I get the data from the specific object that I touched.

How do I do this, thanks!

I have not tried anything yet as I do not know where to start.

Comment: Why don't you go to youtube and learn the fundamentals of ScriptableObjects before trying to do something?

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly attach ScriptableObjects to GameObjects. You'll need to make a MonoBehaviour that handles it, which will look something like this

```
public class MyScriptableObjectHandler: MonoBehaviour
{
    public MyScriptableObjectType data;
}
```

And then, in the collision function, you retrieve it like this:

```
collidedObject.GetComponent<MyScriptableObjectHandler>().data;
```